# Upgrading to PHP 7 disabled SimpleXML mod in CentOS

Tags: php, centos, simplexml, php-7

I need to enable SimpleXML mod on PHP7 in CentOS.

On my ubuntu server it was as easy as

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Any idea how to do that on centOS ?

I tried installing the webtatic and epel-release packages, but for some reason they mess up yum and every execution of yum produces a "xz compression not supported" error.

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution with remi's repository

install the Remi repository by downloading the appropriate RPM package for your system and installing it.

CentOS and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.x

```
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm
```

CentOS and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.x

```
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-7*.rpm
```

If you get a File Not Found error message when trying to download the package, the version number might have changed. You can access the latest version of the RPM installer from the Remi Repository Configuration page.

remi was disabled by default in my case after adding them so I enabled them as follows to update PHP again

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php70 install php70 php-common
```

Restarted apache

```
apachectl restart
```

The SimpleXML module will now also be visible in

```
  $php -m
```

Comment: See the wizard instructions  on https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/ especially about instruction how to permanently enable the "remi-php70" repository (which only provides PHP), to avoid issue, when later, trying to add additional extensions.